# Spring Boot MVC not using model values in JSP

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am working on an Spring Boot MVC application. My issue is that when the view appears, it does not parse the values from the Model.

**application.properties**

```
spring.application.name=test-mvc
server.context-path=/test-mvc
```

**Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;
    }
}
```

**Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/view")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);

        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

**greeting.jsp**

```
<html>
 <head><title>Hello world Example</title></head>
 <body>
     <h1>Hello ${name}, How are you?</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

Output from http://localhost:8080/test-mvc/view/greeting?name=Mikey:

> Hello ${name}, How are you?

I have also tried returning a ModelAndView. I am not sure why it's not putting "Mikey" in where `${name}` is.

**Update**

Every time I add a taglib or anything to the JSP page, it displays the page source. It doesn't render the page. Below is my `pom.xml`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <hibernate.version>5.0.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    <postgres.version>9.4.1208</postgres.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: @shinjw - I don't have a web.xml. With Spring Boot, it shouldn't be needed

Comment: <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> Try adding this to the top of your jsp. also make sure your maven pom.xml includes jstl

Comment: @shinjw - I am just using HTML. I am not doing a <c:out> or anything, so that tag won't do anything.

Comment: Try adding <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; 
charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%> to the top of the page

Comment: It just displays the whole page source, doesn't change anything

Comment: Did you try this `<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>`? What about a simple `Model` instead of your `ModelMap`?

Comment: @engineer - I provided an update. It seems the JSP doesn't render properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below dependencies in your `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

You might have to add below dependency to avoid `javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType`. 
If you don't add this as `scope=required` then *tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar* will be placed in your `Tomcat 8.0\webapps\AppName\WEB-INF\lib` folder and will cause above error.
You don't need to add below dependency if you run your app from IDE or `mvn Spring-boot:run` command.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then visit - http://localhost:8080/AppName/view/greeting?name=Mikey

Check this repo for [Complete Source Code](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/Spring-Boot-Jsp-Demo).

**UPDATE:**
The issue [Tomcat war deployment of JSP sample is not working due to "tomcat-embed-el" dependency](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5454) is fixed in [Spring Boot - 1.4.0.M2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/)

Comment: I added all three to my pom and did a new Maven Install. Now when I go to the URL, the Controller is not reached and the page comes up empty

Comment: Have you checked this [repo](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/Spring-Boot-Jsp-Demo)? I have mapped the exact url that you asked in the question.

Comment: I got it to work. It was because I had the Config in the wrong place. Thank you for the help!

Comment: FYI, I have created this [Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5454) regarding **tomcat-embed-el** dependency being added transitively.