# Spring Boot problems with JSP file

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a similar problem as this [JSP file not rendering in Spring Boot web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602010/jsp-file-not-rendering-in-spring-boot-web-application)

But suggested answer is unfortunately not working for me.

I created project using start.spring.io service, and the default structure was

```
/src/main/java
/src/main/resources/templates
/src/main/resources/static
```

I have a JSP page called `add.jsp`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>Add</body>
</html>
```

which I tried to put in /src/main/resources/templates This was not working at all, then I created new folder webapp and put my jsp file there like this:

```
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/add.jsp
```

In browser (I tried Chrome and Safari) I get the contents of file, not

```
Add
```

Here is my code from configuration:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
}
```

I have these dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Maybe I should put my jsp files in other folder or add other resolver? 
Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

**UPDATE**
If I add `<!DOCTYPE html>` my jsp would partially work, but not in full, namely

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

is displayed, when it shouldn't. Where could the problem lie?

Comment: Read this, and follow the example. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I followed the example in full and it helped!

Comment: Sorry, I was happy too early. My jsp is only partially displayed. But for example this part is for some reason shown on the page 
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Comment: Try this [Demo](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/Spring-Boot-Jsp-Demo). Also see this [QnA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110386/spring-boot-mvc-not-using-model-values-in-jsp?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: Thank you! The QnA is the same as mine, but dependency issue didin't help me. I created new project with Spring Boot - 1.4.0.M2 - still no luck. But I will try to search further in dependencies issue

Comment: Have you tried this [Demo](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/Spring-Boot-Jsp-Demo)? Its based on Boot 1.3.3.